# How to link a ProfileModel to a SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have stored data with SharedPreference, I would like to retrieve them now by going through functions

The stored data:

```
dataUser = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = dataUser.edit();
    editor.putString("date", dateString);
    editor.commit();
```

My ProfileModel:

```
public class ProfileModel {

    private String date;

    public ProfileModel() {
    }

    public ProfileModel(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

From the ProfileModel, I want to retrieve the value of the `putString ("date", ...)` with getDate()

So what gives in a text this `dateTxt.setText(String.valueOf(model.getDate()));`

**How I relate the ProfileModel to my stored data ?**
(Having already done this with Firebase, connect the two data this:

```
ProfileModel model = snapshot.getValue(ProfileModel.class);
```

The `snapshot` this is the name of the DataSnapshot, so I have to find something similar in SharedPreference

Comment: To be clear, you want to store the ProfileModel data in the SharedPreference, but as a child of a 'user'? Do you have multiple users' data to store?

Comment: I modified hoping it's more understandable

Answer (score 0):

implement this library on build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
```

you can save the entire custom object in shared pref in string by using gson library.
To Save any model ->

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject;
//set variables of 'myObject', etc.
Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myObject);
prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

For Getting the object

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

Now you can access your obj like all other model class

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be putting the SharedPreferences logic in the model constructor:

```
public ProfileModel(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("userData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String dateString = prefs.getString("date", <some-default-value>);
    this.date = dateString;
}
```

This would be an additional constructor along with the 2 you already have.

Then use it like this:

```
ProfileModel model = new ProfileModel(getApplicationContext());
dateTxt.setText(model.getDate());
```

This should work, cheers!